# Akka - How to block on the entire loop rather than each message received

Tags: scala, akka

I'm attempting to write an actor hierarchy that parallelizes finding a number between 0 and 5.

Here is my code:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

class A1 extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case "test" => {
      val r = new scala.util.Random
      val r1 = 0 + r.nextInt(( 5 - 0) + 1)
      if(r1 == 1) {
        sender() ! "found"
      }
      else {
        sender() ! "NotFound"
      }

    }
  }
}


object BTest extends App{

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("firstActorSystem")
  val a1 = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[A1], "A1")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  var answer = ""
  while(answer != "found") {
    answer = Await.result(a1 ? "test", timeout.duration).toString
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("answer : " + answer)
  }
}
```

which prints some variety of below depending on when the number `1` is found :

```
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : NotFound
answer : found
```

I'm unsure how to execute the actors concurrently while blocking until the number `1` is found.
I think my solution blocks until each actor message is received using `Await.result`.

How to block on the entire loop rather than each message received and unblock when the number `1` is found?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question boils down to how to compose multiple `Future`s until one of them returns the value you're insterested in. You probably want some cap on the number of concurrently running futures at any given time.

You could achieve it using Akka Streams like this:

```scala
implicit val materializer: Materializer = Materializer(actorSystem)

val maxConcurrency = 16

val future = 
  Source.repeat(1)
        .mapAsync(maxConcurrency)(_ => a1 ? "test")
        .filter("found" == _)
        .runWith(Sink.head)

Await.result(future , timeout.duration).toString
```